# TableItem - center image

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am wanting to center my image.

Here is some what I am doing:

```
    String[] emailString = new String[2];
    emailString[0] = emailText.getText();
    emailString[1] = "";

    emailList.add(emailString);
    emailItems.add(new TableItem(emailTable, SWT.NONE)); //I have tried SWT.CENTER here but it only centers the text.

    for(int i = 0; i < emailItems.size(); i++){
        TableItem item = emailItems.get(i);
        item.setText(emailList.get(i));
        item.setImage(1, Images.getImage("remove.png"));
    }
```

So there are two columns: email and remove. In the remove column (column 1), I am wanting to center the image. You can see that I am setting the image in the for loop. But how do you center it?

Here is a visual of what is happening:

[image]

Comment: Related question which might provide an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968352/how-to-align-image-to-center-of-table-cell-swt-table

Comment: do we have to do it manually?

Comment: Yes, this has to be done using the SWT.PaintItem event

Comment: Okay, that works. I just feel like this is a heavy way of centering an image.