# I can't find class OwnerDrawLabelProvider in Jface jars and field SWT.PaintItem

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I try to use code example from this answer: [How to align image to center of table cell (SWT Table)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968352/how-to-align-image-to-center-of-table-cell-swt-table)
But I can't find class in jar:

```
org.eclipse.jface.viewers.OwnerDrawLabelProvider
```

I am using next jar:

```
org.eclipse.rap.jface-2.3.1.20140819-1926.jar
```

I also tried to find field SWT.PaintItem in next

```
org.eclipse.rap.rwt-2.3.1.20140909-1638.jar
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OwnerDrawLabelProvider` is in the `org.eclipse.jface` plugin.

The `org.eclipse.rap.xxxx` plugins you reference are part of Eclipse RAP not the core Eclipse JFace/SWT code.