# How to align image to center of table cell (SWT Table) RAP Platform

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, rcp, eclipse-rap

I found some solutions for this question, but they are for RCP Platform only. I'm using RAP Platform and I can't find a solution.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968352/how-to-align-image-to-center-of-table-cell-swt-table

Comment: The suggestion from @flafoux won't work in RAP as it does not support owner-drawn table items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To custom-align images, you have two choices in RAP:

**Markup**

After preparing the table accordingly, you can use a subset of HTML with the table items's text.

```java
Table table = new Table( parent, SWT.NONE );
table.setData( RWT.MARKUP_ENABLED, Boolean.TRUE );
table.setData( RWT.CUSTOM_ITEM_HEIGHT, Integer.valueOf( 80 ) );

TableItem item = new TableItem( table, SWT.NONE );
String imageUrl = RWT.getRequest().getContextPath() + "/" + registerImage( "foo.png" );
item.setText( "<img src='" + imageUrl + "' width='10' height='10' style='padding-right:5px'/>" );
```

The code to register an image (here the image is assumed to be located on the class path) should look like this:

```java
String registerImage( String resourceName ) throws IOException {
  IResourceManager resourceManager = RWT.getResourceManager();
  if( !resourceManager.isRegistered( resourceName ) ) {
    InputStream inputStream = CLASSLOADER.getResourceAsStream( resourceName );
    try {
      resourceManager.register( resourceName, inputStream );
    } finally {
      inputStream.close();
    }
  }
  return resourceManager.getLocation( resourceName );
}
```

More details can be found here: http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/09/12/making-your-images-available-using-markup/

**Row Templates**

With row templates, the default column layout of tables can be replaced and the way items layout their cells can be changed.

To change to position of an image, it is set as usual with `item.setImage( ... )` and then a template is created that positions the image as desired.
Finally the table is told to make use of the template with `table.setData( ... )`.

```java
Template template = new Template();
ImageCell imageCell = new ImageCell( template );
imageCell.setBindingIndex( 0 ); // bind to image from column 0
imageCell.setTop( 4 ).setLeft( 4 ).setWidth( 48 ).setHeight( 48 );

table.setData( RWT.ROW_TEMPLATE, template );
```

More on this here: http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/11/14/rap-2-2m3-introducing-row-templates/