# Java SWT: How to center content of a column in a Table?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, windowbuilder

I need to center the content of the cells of the fourth column of my table, now they start on left.

This is the table:

```
    Table membersTable = new Table(clubComposite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.CHECK | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    membersTable.setLinesVisible(true);
    membersTable.setHeaderVisible(true);
    membersTable.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));

    TableColumn tblclmnName = new TableColumn(membersTable, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnName.setWidth(150);
    tblclmnName.setText("Nombre");

    TableColumn tblclmnCommonPhoneNumber = new TableColumn(membersTable, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnCommonPhoneNumber.setWidth(120);
    tblclmnCommonPhoneNumber.setText("Teléfono");

    TableColumn tblclmnCommonMoney = new TableColumn(membersTable, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnCommonMoney.setWidth(150);
    tblclmnCommonMoney.setText("Participación Habitual");

    TableColumn tblclmnPayed = new TableColumn(membersTable, SWT.CENTER);
    tblclmnPayed.setWidth(50);
    tblclmnPayed.setText("Pagado"); 

    // populate Table
    for (int i=0; i<50; i++) {
        TableItem tableItem = new TableItem(membersTable, SWT.CENTER);                  
        tableItem.setText(new String[] {"person "+i, "610610620", "100", ""});
        tableItem.setImage(3, uncheckedImage);
    }
```

I tried doing this:

```
TableColumn tblclmnPayed = new TableColumn(membersTable, SWT.CENTER);
```

But it seems that it only centers the title of the column, not it's content.

It is possible to achieve my needs on Java SWT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to center the content of a column, you need to specify the `SWT.CENTER` style bit for the `TableItem` as well.

For example:

```
final Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
table.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
table.setHeaderVisible(true);
table.setLinesVisible(true);

final TableColumn column1 = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
column1.setText("Column 1");
column1.setWidth(75);

final TableColumn column2 = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
column2.setText("Column 2");
column2.setWidth(75);

final TableColumn column3 = new TableColumn(table, SWT.CENTER);
column3.setText("Column 3");
column3.setWidth(75);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    new TableItem(table, SWT.CENTER).setText(new String[] { "a", "b", "c" });
}
```

Note that this will only affect the contents for the column which also specifies `SWT.CENTER`, not the content for the other columns.

---

***Edit*** in regards to centering an image:

I don't believe it is possible to center an image within the table row via the style bits, since they seem to be ignored.

One alternative would be to use a paint listener to draw the image with the correct padding to center the image in the column (See: [How to align image to center of table cell (SWT Table)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968352/how-to-align-image-to-center-of-table-cell-swt-table/8973408)). Note that with this method the row is not resized based on the size of the image, so unless your image is tiny/the same height as the row, you'll have to do some additional work to keep the image form being cut off.

Comment: didn't work. Maybe it's because the content is a image? I edited my post adding the code where i add the image

Comment: @NullPointerException I'm not sure it's possible to center an image within the row using the style bits - I've added an edit with an alternative that may work in your situation.